# Why is my winforms project immediately closing?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I was editing my project and tweaking it, I decided to test it, but it won't run.
When I looked in the console, it closed with an exit code of 0.
Is it a Visual Studio bug? I'm on Visual Studio 2022, by the way.
If it is a code problem, here is the code on Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Flipbook
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics g;
        Pen p;
        Brush b;
        bool d = false;
        int tool = 1;
        int width = 10;
        Point m1;
        Point m2;
        int selectedframe = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void undoInCurrentPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void redoInCurrentPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void cutCurrentPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tool = 3;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tool = 1;
        }

        private void copyCurrentPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pastePageToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void addPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imageList1.Images.Add(Flipbook.Properties.Resources.blank);
        }

        private void deleteThisPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imageList1.Images.RemoveAt(selectedframe);
        }

        private void flipToTheNextPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedframe++;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[selectedframe];
        }

        private void flipToThePreviousPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(selectedframe == 0))
            {
                selectedframe--;
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
                pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[selectedframe];
            }
        }

        private void newAnimationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView2.Items.Clear();
            listView2.Items.Add("", selectedframe);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
            b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            d = true;
            m1 = e.Location;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            d = false;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            m2 = e.Location;
            p.Color = panel2.BackColor;
            p.Width = width;
            b = new SolidBrush(panel2.BackColor);
            if (d)
            {
                switch (tool)
                {
                    case 1:
                        g.DrawLine(p, m1, m2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        g.FillEllipse(b, e.X, e.Y, width, width);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.White), e.X, e.Y, width, width);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tool = 2;
        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            width = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        }

        private void panel2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
            if (cd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                panel2.BackColor = cd.Color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Flipbook
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to reload visual studio, tweak some settings, and I was expecting it to run normally, but the program immediately closed.

Comment: InitializeComponent() is failing.  InitiailizeComponent runs the code in the designer.cs file and if designer has errors the code will stop running.

Comment: When I go into the designer, it has no issues of loading.

Comment: Is `Form1` being invoked at all?  If you place a debugging breakpoint in its constructor, is that ever reached?  If not then it sounds like the problem is outside of this class.

Comment: It's not executing InitializeComponent. I set the breakpoint to remove once hit, but it doesn't remove itself. Same in the program file.

Comment: _Is it a Visual Studio bug?_ This should be the last question you ask. Though it is possible it is highly unlikely. Usually the problem is in your code.

Comment: I don't see any problems in the code.

Comment: Have you tried to repair VS2022 (I don't think VS2023 exists)? Or reboot? All is fine in your code, except if there are other classes like David pointed out.

Comment: The designer file is not running when you view the tab.  You are having issues when running the designer code.  Put a break point after InitializeComponent and see if you hit the break point.

Comment: look for the contents of "Output" tab (Debug -> Windows -> Output) after running your program. It should show the exception that occurred. Most probably some event handler is implicitly called on program startup and has an unhandled exception.

Comment: It had no errors while running (imlokesh), and my breakpoint didn't hit (jdweng), Though, I can show you the other classes. (Fredy)

Comment: if the mouse move over the pictureBox1, I have an exception because the variable p is not instancied.

Comment: just realized it says exit code 0, so there are probably no unhandled exceptions... I would start by eliminating latest code you wrote one by one (given the program worked in past). Maybe some code or external library is closing form or using threads directly (incorrectly). If you suspect vs issues, you can build in release mode and run the exe directly.

Comment: for more info: https://treedeveloper.net/media/runningflipbook.mp4

Comment: I changed the version of .NET to 4.8, and it ran!

Comment: Where is your main

Comment: Already fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My answer probably wont help you, since i cant imagine you changed some of that, but i still give it a shot.
First, check your program.cs file, there should be a line

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Check that there is indeed Form1 after new.

Second, go to Project -> Properties, check if under Output Type stands Windows Application.

Third thing, go to Project -> Configure Startup Project. Check if indeed the right project is selected as startup.

Comment: Where is Configure Startup Project?

Comment: At the top, you find File - Edit - View..... - Project -. After you clicked on Project, you will se configure Startup Projects (it has a settings icon), you cant miss it.

Comment: Is it the wrench or the cog? If you are asking about the cog, then it says "Set as Startup Project."

Comment: You can also right click on the Project in the Solution Explorer, and there you will find Configure Startup Projects.

Answer (score 0):

It may not work if you have an antivirus because antiviruses may delete the content of your new projects. Try deactivating it and check if it put your project to quarantine if you use one